# Having trouble installing mongodb on macOS bigsur

Tags: mongodb, installation

```
Warning: No available formula with the name "mongosh" (dependency of mongodb/brew/mongodb-community). Did you mean mongocli?
```

==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
This similarly named formula was found:
mongocli
To install it, run:
brew install mongocli
It was migrated from mongodb/brew to homebrew/core.

this is what is says in the terminal after writing `brew tap mongodb/brew` . Im trying to us homebrew to install mongodb on macOS bigsur

Answer (score 0):

To use MongoDB shell mongosh, you need to download it from here https://downloads.mongodb.com/compass/mongosh-1.2.2-darwin-x64.zip

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).